# How to delete a record from a non-queryable object

Tags: soql, rest-api, mobilesdk, delete, record

I'm trying to delete a record from `MobilePushServiceDevice` object. This object is not `queryable`, however, it is `deletable`.

How can I delete a specific record from this object if I can't query it in order to obtain a list of records to delete?

**Update:**

Also, I don't have the `Id` of the records to delete. All I know is that I need to delete records that have a reference to specific `User` record, and I know that they are referencing a `User` record because I can open the list of the `MobilePushServiceDevice` records by going to **https://INSTANCE.salesforce.com/0FG** and see the list of available fields if I select the `Create New View` link (note that I can't access this object neither through Schema Builder or Workbench).

[image]

So, something like this would do the trick in a normal SQL DB:

> DELETE FROM MobilePushServiceDevice WHERE User = 'USER_ID'

Comment: Did you write an mobile application using mobile sdk?

Comment: Yes, using the Salesforce MobileSDK for Hybrid app (Ionic 2)

Comment: Cordova plugin? Did you try to use unregisterSalesforceNotifications(user account) method?

Comment: I couldn't find that method. How do you reference it from JavaScript, since it's a Hybrid app?

Comment: I only know this method by searching github repository for unregister event for push notification. (also this is the reason why I'm commenting instead of replying) You can search unregister on this github org (https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin) then use unregister method similar to how you use register event for registering push notification.

Comment: haha, that's the same thing I did a a few hours earlier today :) I did found some methods there, but non are exposed and callable from JavaScript. Plus, the registration occurs automatically under the hood when the user logs in, and un-registration when the user logs out, so I don't really have the control. I guess I'll give it another look tomorrow when I get back to office.

Comment: Is there any way I can get connection tokens from this list ? I really in a need